# Handle over a cypress.io testcase to non-technical Users

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, node-modules, cypress

I've written a testcase with cypress.io which is working fine.
I want that a couple of non-technical people can run this test from their local machines.

My assume was:

- Install node-js on the local machines
- unzip my project and change to this directory
- run `./node_modules/.bin/cypress open`

Problem is that the users get the error that cypress is not installed. is there any solution that the users don't have to run `npm install cypress --save-dev` first? in my understanding i deliver the cypress installation right within my project?

Pls see my project structure here:

[image]

Comment: See [Direct Download](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Direct-download), might do the job although I've not tried it.

Comment: thanks, indeed does the trick here and is the simplest solution for my users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your project you should have a package.json file with cypress in it

`"devDependencies": {"cypress": "^4.0.0"}`

after they install nodejs, they just need to go into the folder and run `npm install` or `npm i` for short.

if you ever encounter an issue with the `npm` command, use `npx` instead

Comment: simplest solution in my case is to use the direct cypress download (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Direct-download)

Comment: But then if you want to update the version you need to tell them to download again, I still recommend package.json since they need to do npm install anyway